# Do I need to use VisualStateManager if my target device is only one kind?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am developing a windows 10 app and I want it to run only on a desktop with 27 inches LED screen. The will display numbers in three columns. The only requirement is that the text(numbers) should increase or decrease when the app (app's window?) is maximized or made smaller, i.e., the content of the app's display should scale with the size of the app's window size.

I initially tried VisualStateManager, but I've found out that VisualStateManager is meant for. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

For your question, since your app targets on desktop, `VisualStateManager` can be used in your app and it can be meaningful. As you said:

> The only requirement is that the text(numbers) should increase or decrease when the app (app's window?) is maximized or made smaller, i.e., the content of the app's display should scale with the size of the app's window size.

1. Actually the `VisualStateManager` is not only designed for making the layout adapt to different devices, in the [VisualState.StateTriggers property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.statetriggers.aspx) you can define the [AdaptiveTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx), it represents a declarative rule that applies visual states based on window properties. Also it makes it possible to see the effects of these adaptive changes directly on the XAML design surface in Microsoft Visual Studio. In one word, `AdaptiveTrigger` is not designed for the layout of different devices, it is designed for adaptation of different window's size of your app, if your app targets on desktop, then your app's window size can be changed by user, the layout can be changed base on the window's size.
2. `AdaptiveTrigger` is one usage of `VisualStateManeger`, another is [VisualStateManager.GoToState method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate.aspx). Just for example, when you edit copies of styles as enabled by the XAML design surface, the visual states from the default template are defined in the XAML you are editing, transitions between two states are generally used by requesting a new `VisualState` by name.

So, `VisualStateManager` can be used in your app and it can be meaningful, but it's not essential, it's up to your layout.  **But** for your scenario, I think maybe what you need is a [GridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx), it is a control that displays data items in rows and columns and it can automatically adapt to the window's size, you can refer to the official [ListView and GridView sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView) to see how to make it works.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it. But from what I have read about both 'VisualStateManager' and 'AdaaptiveTrigger' both are used to set changes for discrete states. Is there a way to bind all the elements inside the page to the app's window such that the size of each element is in a way inherited according to the app's window size? Pardon me if I am not making sense.